# OpenFooter + tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Добрый день!

Помогите доделать скрипт, уже потратил все силы.
[`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/zd6yswta/), не получается доделать его таким образом, что бы он выезжал(а не fade эффект) из футера по клику, а при переключении что бы он просто работал как эффект Tab

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zd6yswta/3/

Comment: При двойном клике по кнопке не сворачивается блок

Comment: Могли бы самостоятельно дописать эти две строчки. В данной версии поправил небольшую ошибку в removeClass. Убрал точку. https://jsfiddle.net/zd6yswta/4/